# How do I make winsound play a sound as long as the key that activates the playsound is pressed?

Tags: python

I want to make a program that plays .wav files on keypress for corresponding values, like *w.wav* for *w*.

But I don’t want it to fully play the sound. I want it to play as long as it has been pressed like if *w* is held down for 0.5 seconds the sound, also will be played for 0.5 seconds, but it has to be at the same time, not like if you pressed it down for 0.5 seconds it plays it for 0.5 seconds right after recording the time pressed.

Like it stops all the playsound function when the key is not being held down any more, I am not going to provide my code as it is basically:

```
import keyboard
import winsound

x = keyboard.read_key()
y = '\\', x, '.wav'
winsound.PlaySound(y, winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Yeah, I hope this post doesn’t die in new as this question was never asked ever before.

Comment: What do you want to do if the key is held longer than the .wav file? Loop?

Comment: yeah, then end as the key is unheld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I've never used the `keyboard` library and I don't have the ability to download so I can't really test it. I hope this can get you started at least.**

Looking at the [**`winsound`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html) documentation, I see two things that might be able to help you. When using the `PlaySound` method, you can pass `None` as the sound argument to cancel any currently playing sounds.

> If the `sound` parameter is `None`, any currently playing waveform sound is stopped. If the system indicates an error, `RuntimeError` is raised.

Additionally, you can pass the `winsound.SND_LOOP` (along with `winsound.SND_ASYNC`) to play your sound continuously.

> `winsound.SND_LOOP`: Play the sound repeatedly. The `SND_ASYNC` flag must also be used to avoid blocking. Cannot be used with `SND_MEMORY`.

Now that we have the necessary tools, we can start solving our problem. We need to write a script that captures keypresses and loops the sound from a certain file until that key is released.

In your main function, you'll want setup different events for the `keyboard.on_press` and `keyboard.on_release` events.

```py
import winsound

import keyboard

PLAY_FLAGS = winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_LOOP | winsound.SND_FILENAME
# Play the file name asynchronously and loop it

def press_callback(e):
    if e.name not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        return # Filter anything you want
    path = f"//{e.name}.wav"
    winsound.PlaySound(path, PLAY_FLAGS)
    return

def release_callback(e):
    winsound.PlaySound(None, PLAY_FLAGS) # Cancels ALL playing sounds
    return

def main():
    keyboard.on_press(callback=press_callback)
    keyboard.on_release(callback=release_callback)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem with this is that you can play as many sounds as you want by holding down multiple keys, but as soon as you release a key, all sounds stop because of the `winsound.PlaySound(None, PLAY_FLAGS)` call. To tackle this, I would put these methods into a class and have an instance attribute reflect the currently playing sounds. When there is a request to stop the sound (key release event), stop all sounds, remove the requested sound, then start the remaining sounds back up. Whether this delay is noticeable or not is another story. I don't have speakers to test with so I'll leave that up to you if you go with this approach.